# Pagination loop is stuck at x > 99

Tags: r, web-scraping, pagination

I am scraping some data from an API, and my code works just fine as long as I extract pages 0 to 98. Whenever my loop reaches 99, I get an error `Error: Internal Server Error (HTTP 500).`.

Tried to find an answer but I am only proficient in R and C# and cannot understand Python or other.

```
keywords = c('ABC OR DEF')

parameters <- list(
  'q'       = keywords,
  num_days = 1,
  language = 'en',
  num_results = 100,
  page = 0,
  'api_key' = '123456'
)

response <- httr::GET(get_url, query = parameters)

# latest_page_number <- get_last_page(parsed)

httr::stop_for_status(response)

content <- httr::content(response, type = 'text', encoding = 'utf-8')

parsed  <- jsonlite::fromJSON(content, simplifyVector = FALSE, simplifyDataFrame = TRUE)

num_pages = round(parsed[["total_results"]]/100)
print(num_pages)

result = parsed$results
for(x in 1:(num_pages))
{
  print(x)
  parameters <- list(
    'q' = keywords,
    page = x,
    num_days = 7,
    language = 'en',
    num_results = 100,
    'api_key' = '123456'
  )
  response <- httr::GET(get_url, query = parameters)
  
  httr::stop_for_status(response)
  
  content <- httr::content(response, type = 'text', encoding = 'utf-8')
  # content <- httr::content(response)
  
  parsed  <- jsonlite::fromJSON(content, simplifyVector = FALSE, simplifyDataFrame = TRUE)
  
  Sys.sleep(0.2)
  
  result = rbind(result,parsed$results[,colnames(result)])
  
}
```

Comment: 500 can be everything... have a look at "safefly" from the `purrr` package to prevent your code from throwing and error and stopping and check if on interation 100 if it works or not.

Comment: In the very beginning I set page =0. I can set page = anything below 99 and it will work. So not a loop thing maybe. What can prevent me accessing page 100?

Comment: sorry i did not speak about a status, i spoke about the iterator. Since you rbind all data you could "ignore" the error. There is a nice tutorial by "Colin Fay" about web scraping with `purrr`. Just search for it :-)

Comment: any page I input over page 99 is an error. Might it be related to my database?